# Google Maps JavaScript API is working in localhost but not in Live Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

**Currently, I'm trying to implement Google Map Autofill address functionality to get the address latitude and longitude on my website.**
I've created a Google Maps JavaScript API key on Google Console and insert the API key in the script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[api_key]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

when I'm running the project in localhost, it's giving me the autofill suggestion addresses along with the latitude and longitude for the particular address which I've chosen.
But, when I'm trying to run the project on a live server it's giving me several errors. Fixed all the errors, but still, it's not giving me the result.
Tried for 5-6 days, tried different APIs, but the result is same.

Even I copied the code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform and inserted my API key, but nothing seems working.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Comment: Is your website running over http or https?

Comment: Did you add the domain in the google console? any errors in console?

Comment: its running over http @George

Comment: I've added the domain name and its sub-domain name where I'm currently testing this one.At first, the Key was Public but now I changed it into Restrict Key with the domain names.
I'm getting "Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError" and "Your site URL to be authorized"
testing url is [link](http://test.digiegeeks.com/gmap/)
for your information I'm using Google Map Javascript API @ToniMichelCaubet

Comment: also tried on a secure domain [https://p4programming.net/gmap/](https://p4programming.net/gmap/) result is still the same @George

Comment: after a long time managed to fix the issue. It was caused by a javascript error.

Comment: also, it's working both on HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is indicating that the API key used has referrer restrictions, and the domain you are trying to use the API key on is not an authorized referrer.

It's possible that you may need to add asterisks for wildcards to your authorized referrers. For example your test link:

http://test.digiegeeks.com/gmap/

You should authorize something like:

```
*.digiegeeks.com/*
```

Or for your secure p4programming domain you mentioned, something like this:

```
*.p4programming.net/*
```

If you include asterisks as shown above as wildcards, do you still get the referrer error?

I hope this helps!

Comment: "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console" -  I'm getting this even after the API had been enabled

Comment: Based on your script tag in the original post, it looks like you will need to enable both places and JavaScript API. Have you enabled both of them?